# php-page with db connection

Tags: php

Where do I have to store a PHP file in Wordpress so that I can set up a DB connection.

I am currently using this directory but it doesn't work.
D:\WordPress\xampp\htdocs\myproject\specialsite\redirect.php

The aim is to call up the PHP file via the URL http://www.myproject.de/specialsite/redirect.php.

How do I get the DB connection and also this URL?

Comment: Welcome to wpse, you can require the root file, `wp-config.php`, if this file is not part of the wordpress hierarchy. Then you will have all the WordPress functions available, including the object that is responsible for everything DB, `global $wpdb;`.

Answer (score 0):

This file to access WordPress default functions has to be inside the WordPress folder. It's the best practice to create a plugin if you want to add custom features. WordPress provide directory path and URL's functions with which you can get the path of any specific file. Please visit the following links to understand how these functions work.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

Absolute path to the WordPress directory is defined by a constant named as ABSPATH.

And for database you can use WordPress global database object [global $wpdb;](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)